# i want to access data that is in another state in another component to this component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state-management

i want to access data that is in another state in another component to this component. i had made a popup in which comes with the h1 titles but i can't retrieve the value that is  in another state in anoterh component. i have tried like this but it only shows the title but no values. how can i do it in react js functional components.

```
import React from 'react'
import data from "./MyVehicles"
import "./InfoYes.css"

function Info({ setShowInfoYes }) {
    return (
        <div className="modal">
      <div className="box">
         
          <h1 className="h1__info"> Name: {data.name}</h1>
            <h1 className="h1__info"> Vehicle type: {data.vechiletype}</h1>
            <h1 className="h1__info"> vehicle name: {data.selectvehicle}</h1>
            <h1 className="h1__info"> registration date: {data.registrationdate}</h1>
            <h1 className="h1__info"> tax expire date: {data.taxexpiredate}</h1>
            <h1 className="h1__info"> pick up: {data.pickup}</h1>
            <button className="calculate__button">Calculate</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default Info
```

Comment: your problem is a bit unclear,could you please elaborate it a  bit more?

Comment: i want to render the values that i enter in previous page i.e. another component which is a form which i have put values in the data state .

Comment: could you paste the code of that other component as well ?

Comment: @NikhilRoka You can [lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: @Sakshi yes sure...done.

Comment: you can pass that data as a props from first component to second.

Comment: @vijaykasar can you help wit the code.

Comment: i only want to get with the react context or by the props ways @vijaykasar.

Answer (score 0):

below is your Form compoennt:

```
...code...
return (
        ..other divs..
    <Info data={data} setShowInfoYes={provide some value here}/>
    )
```

Info component:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./InfoYes.css"

export default ({ data, setShowInfoYes }) => {
 
  return(
<div className="modal">
      <div className="box">
         
          <h1 className="h1__info"> Name: {data.name}</h1>
            <h1 className="h1__info"> Vehicle type: {data.vechiletype}</h1>
            <h1 className="h1__info"> vehicle name: {data.selectvehicle}</h1>
            <h1 className="h1__info"> registration date: {data.registrationdate}</h1>
            <h1 className="h1__info"> tax expire date: {data.taxexpiredate}</h1>
            <h1 className="h1__info"> pick up: {data.pickup}</h1>
            <button className="calculate__button">Calculate</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  )
  
}
```

If setShowInfoYes is present in Info's prop then it's value will also be have to passed ,not just the value of data.

Comment: i can't understand what you are trying to do?!.

Comment: you want to pass `data` from Form component to Info component right?so this is how you will write it inside the form component's return  ,like `<Info data={data}/>` this way you are passing data to Info component

Comment: And if you want to access data inside the Info then simply render it like `{data}` or `{data.name}` and so on.

Comment: if i pass data props to info it gets error coz i already have another setShowInfoYes to info , plus i want to render the values from previous component to the info component side by side of the h1 titles.

like:
name : (Value for previous form component)
vehicle type : (Value from previous form component)

Comment: yes i have done like {data.name} , {data.vehciletype} etc before did you check the code above?

Comment: the code you write in the above form component gives error and i can't understand it.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'vehicletype' of undefined

Comment: this error is beacause your `data` is undefined.

Comment: yeah but i have imported it and pass as props ... but when i dont pass as prop there is no error but the values also don't appear only the h1 appears like:
vehicle type:
vehicle name:
registration date:
expire date:

all blank

Comment: setShowInfoYes={provide some value here} what should i put here??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226339/discussion-between-sakshi-and-nikhil-roka).